# Try to verify data selected is 3 business days out

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a time off list in SharePoint and we need to make sure the employees select dates that are at least 3 business days in the future. I currently have the formula below in the Column Validation field....

=IF([Requested Day Off]>TODAY()+2,TRUE,FALSE)

This works great during the week, but come Thursday or Friday, they can request Monday off. I have created a another column named [3 Business Days Out] that has a calculated value formula below......

=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>3,TODAY()+5,IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>1,TODAY()+3,TODAY()+4))

This returns the magical date I need. But now when I try to place a formula of =[Requested Day Off]>=[3 Business Days Out] in the list validation part of the site, I am getting an error message of "Cannot complete this action. Please Try Again". This has become very frustrating and not sure where I am failing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I posted this awhile back and assumed it was working.  Instead, it was preventing them from entering a time of request on the weekend, but on Friday they could still request Monday Off.  If a request is entered on a Wednesday, the earliest would be Monday, on Thursday, we want Tuesday to be the earliest, and Friday we want Wednesday to be the earliest.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because a column validation formula cannot reference any other column. You could use a list item validation formula instead (List Settings, Validation Settings).

For a column validation formula, try this:

```
=AND( [Requested Day Off] > TODAY()+2, WEEKDAY([Requested Day Off],2) < 6 )
```

You don't need the IF's because AND, OR and simple comparisons return True or False by themselves.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening with that second statement.  I want to understand it.  I appreciate it.

Comment: WEEKDAY is an Excel and SharePoint function that returns a number for the day of the week. When the second parameter is set to "2", it returns 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday... 7 for Sunday. So, any day that is less than 6 is a week day.   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WEEKDAY-function-f0aa7aa6-fad7-4e41-aab9-3e77a133f0be